# converting simple json string to object always setting properties to null

Tags: java, json

Working on a java launcher that checks a remote server for the latest version of software available. The server responds with some JSON data, which I'm using gson to convert into an object.

However, the data is always `null` and I can't figure out why. I've done this a dozen times without a problem.

The class gson will use:

```
public class VersionResponse {
    public String currentVersion;
}
```

The code. I've taken a sample json string to avoid any problems with the remote server file. It's valid json, I've verified.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
remoteVersionResponse = gson.fromJson("{\"currentVersion\":\"v.0.0.1-96-g48c1f4d\"}", VersionResponse.class);

if( remoteVersionResponse != null ){
    System.out.println("Object: " + remoteVersionResponse.currentVersion);
}
```

The object's `currentVersion` property is always showing `null`.

I feel like I'm missing something really dumb here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... the obfuscation we have on the build process was breaking the gson's ability to store the values properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VersionResponse {
    public String currentVersion;

    public void setCurrentVersion(String version){
        this.currentVersion = version;
    }  

    public String getCurrentVersion(){
       return this.currentVersion;
    } }
```

Answer (score -1):

your VersionResponse class missing getter and setter

public class VersionResponse {
    public String currentVersion;

```
public void setCurrentVersion(String version){
    this.currentVersion = version;
}  

public String getCurrentVersion(){
    return this.currentVersion;
}
```

}

Comment: Getters and setters are not needed for this. gson should be properly setting the property values. I've used this method a dozen times and I don't see any reason this isn't working. Even their examples don't define any getters/setters. Plus, getters/setters are pretty useless when the property is public